# How to get a nice stack view in radare2?

Tags: reverse-engineering

This is the stack view that I'm getting in radare2 after entering the *visual panel mode*:

[image]

This is the view from immunity debugger:

[image]

how can I get a view similar to that of immunity debugger in radare2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whoever ending up here, I didn't get any response here so I posted the question to Reverse Engineering and radare2 github. you can find the answer [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16844/how-to-get-a-nice-stack-view-in-radare2).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see stack view in r2 you can use Visual mode `VV` or with Print command like this one.

`pxw @ esp`

above Command Print 32bit Hexadecimal word dump.